# Determine with proof whether the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^{3} - 2y^{3}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}$ exists or not

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Define a function $f$ by
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{x^3-2y^3}{x^2+2y^2}.
$$

I want to determine with proof whether or not $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)$$ exists.

**Here's what I've tried:**

I want to find a possible numerical value for the limit so that I can potentially prove that a limit exists with the Squeeze Theorem.

To do so, I approach the point $(0,0)$ along lines of the form $y=mx$ so that the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3-2m^3x^3}{x^2+2m^2x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3(1-2m^3)}{x^2(1+2m^2)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(1-2m^3)}{1+2m^2}=0.
$$

Now that I have a potential limit of $L=0$, I want to "set up" the Squeeze Theorem by finding a $g(x,y)$ such that
$$
|f(x,y)-L|\le g(x,y).
$$

**Here's my problem:**

I'm failing to find a $g(x,y)$ that makes $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}g(x,y)$ easily solvable.
This suggests to me that the limit doesn't actually exist.

In this case, I want to show that the limit does not exist by approaching $(0,0)$ along smooth curves and obtaining a limit value that is not $L=0$, violating the unique property of limits.

How is my approach to this problem? I feel that I'm stuck in a loop of believing the limit exists and trying to find a $g(x,y)$ and believing the limit does not exist and trying to choose some curve at random to approach $(0,0)$ along.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

I would start with noticing that
\begin{align*}
x^{2} \leq x^{2} + 2y^{2} \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}\right|\leq 1 \Rightarrow \left|\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}\right| \leq |x|
\end{align*}
Similarly, the following relation holds:
\begin{align*}
2y^{2} \leq x^{2} + 2y^{2} \Rightarrow \left|\frac{2y^{2}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}\right| \leq 1 \Rightarrow \left|\frac{2y^{3}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}\right| \leq |y|\end{align*}

Now you can apply the squeeze theorem to:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x^{3} - 2y^{3}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x^{3}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}\right|+ \left|\frac{2y^{3}}{x^{2} + 2y^{2}}\right| \leq |x| + |y|
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! So $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} |x| + |y|=0$ by inspection and thus $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0$ by the Squeeze Theorem, correct?

Comment: @SeanXie That's the point!